Different C's, different S's (in order)
The answer is a single word (11 letters long).

 []
 []  [][]
 []  [][]  [][]  [][][][][][][]
 [][][][][][][][][]    []    [][]
   


I believe the downvotes here are unwarranted!

I believe the answer is

 TETROMINOES!


 The picture contains the full tetromino set in alphabetical order (I,J,L,O,S,T,Z) if you break it up like so:
 


As for the title

 It is referring to the fact they have different colours (in Tetris at least) and different shapes.


Nice job, this is it! Was just about to explain the title, but you got it.
